# Not able remove white spaces in HTML of a component in Angular application using .trim() method

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, trim

I am working on an angular application. In HTML of a component within `mat-select` I am trying to remove whiteapces using .trim() method but my application is breaking.
My code

```
<div class="col-2">
    <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select
                    placeholder="Source"
                    [(ngModel)]="applicable.SourceNm.trim()">
                    <mat-option
                            *ngFor="let source of applicableLevel.SourceListTxt.split(',')"
                            [value]="source">
                            {{source.trim()}}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

If I remove the .trim() in ngModel, then the application is working fine. I am not sure what is wrong in using .trim() in ngModel. The error I get is

```
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 32 in [applicableLevel.SourceNm.trim()=$event] in ng:///AdminModule/ConfigurationComponent.html@516:160 ("                                                                                                    [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="applicableLevel.SourceNm.trim()"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-7q1yp3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) You can try pipe for trimming

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
   @Pipe({
      name: 'trim',
      pure: false
   })
    
   export class TrimPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(value: string): any { 
        return value.trim()
      }
      
    }
```

in html   `{{source | trim }}`

dont forget to add `app.modules` `declarations` this pipe.

`ngModel` assings to parameter not to function. So you need to delete `trim()` from `ngModel` and make your `value` as trimmed

```
<div class="col-2">
    <mat-form-field>
            <mat-select
                    placeholder="Source"
                    [(ngModel)]="applicable.SourceNm">
                    <mat-option
                            *ngFor="let source of applicableLevel.SourceListTxt.split(',')"
                            [value]="source | trim">
                            {{source | trim }}
                    </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: in code you didn't also closed mat-select after ngModel.

Comment: in ngmodel dont use trim you need to assing to parameter not to trim function. make your value as trimmed then your model value will be trimmed. I edited answer. Check demo in answer please

Comment: this way, I think I can trim values in `applicableLevel.SourceListTxt`, but I want to trim `applicable.SourceNm`. The initial value of  `applicable.SourceNm` has white spaces. and this value is one among the dropdown. I think I have to do that in .ts